# Search for Arabic text ignoring diacritics, alef hamza differences, and kashida in SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, collation

Well, I have a table with an Arabic column which may contain variant forms of the same word in multiple rows, for example the word "**أسمى**" might be in the following forms:

1. with diacritics: "**أَسْمَى**";
2. with changing the last letter of "ى" into "ي" so it would be like "**أسمي**";
3. with kashida or "ـ" in some part of the word so it would possibly be "**أسمــى**";
4. with variant forms of alef hamza (أ - إ - ا - ء), so it might be "**اسمى**" or "**إسمى**";
5. any combination of the former cases, i.e diacritics and kashida.

I'm looking for a way to store these values in the database (actually I need a solution for SQL Server and another one for Oracle), and to retrieve them regardless of these differences.

I found that I should use an Arabic collation like this Arabic_CI_AI but this collation only helped me in sorting out the problems #1 and #2.

In addition I considered using a fulltext index on the column, but this has its drawbacks and it doesn't provide a full solution.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: In a dev environment like .NET remove the diacritics and store the value in a search column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Comment: thanks Paparazzi, but I'm aware of this. this has the drawback of loosing the exact words, while my situation requires that I should maintain the original text as is, in addition to the search capability. and using a search column would double the required storage

Comment: Oh, no - double the storage.

Comment: @Creative_Q - Paparazzi means *add* an  additional column to store the simplified form of each word, and use that for the search function *only*.

Comment: @Max Vernon, thanks for clarification. I think using extra column would require extra storage.

Comment: well, yes, of course it would.  @Paparazzi offered that as a solution to your *problem*, he didn't say it wouldn't take extra storage.

Comment: You could consider changing collations. In the past (for Greek) I've stored the exact data under Latin1_General_100_CS_AS and then had another "searchable" column with Latin1_General_100_CI_AI which ignores case and accents. Arabic_CS_AI and Arabic_CI_AI exist

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but based on my understanding, this is related to the language/character set.

I use **Oracle database** and I do store arabic values within the database.

The character set I use is **UTF8**, I have also tried storing the different examples provided for the same word and I see it working fine.

I am sure SQL Server also supports such character set.